# Android TCP Server stream reading

Tags: android

I have a .Net c# TCPClient socket communicating with Android TCP server. I am sending an Ascii encoded byte array through SSLStream from tcpclient to server, Android server is responding and reading the stream, but after reading it always shows special characters, but not the exact data. I tried for UTF-8 and other encodings as well with SSLServersocket too. Please help me as Im struggling from one and half day. Thanks in advance..

Client message

```
 byte[] sendingBlob = GenerateMessage(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CLIENTSTATUS + "~" + AuthID + "~"), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("CheckForBusy"));
Generatemessage method will concatenate both length and data as single bytearray and returns it to sendingBLOB which is written to SSLStream
```

Server Socket

```
public void OpenConnection() throws IOException {
    //Create a server socket object and bind it to a port

    ServerSocket socServer = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

    //ServerSocket socServer=SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(SERVER_PORT, 32, InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress());
    //SSLServerSocket socServer= (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(SERVER_PORT, 32, InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress());

    //Create server side client socket reference
    Socket socClient = null;
    //Infinite loop will listen for client requests to connect
    while (true) {
        //Accept the client connection and hand over communication to server side client socket
        socClient =  socServer.accept();
        //For each client new instance of AsyncTask will be created
        ServerAsyncTask serverAsyncTask = new ServerAsyncTask();
        //Start the AsyncTask execution
        //Accepted client socket object will pass as the parameter
        serverAsyncTask.execute(new Socket[] {socClient});
    }
}
```

Reading

```
 InputStream inFromClient = mySocket.getInputStream();
        byte[] data = new byte[4];
        int count = inFromClient.read(data, 0,4);

        String str = new String(data);
```

Output

[image: Image the showing output in androidTCPserver(debug mode)]

Comment: `I am sending an Ascii encoded byte array`. I don't understand what that would be. Show us what you send. Also show us what you receive. If unclear post values in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: I have the edited the question with Asciiencoded byte array as well output.. can u look at the problem and provide a solution as I deadly need it..

Comment: You give unsifficirnt information. I asked you to tell what you send. I see nothing. The only thing i see is tat you receive four bytes withvalues 22,  3, 1, 0. So what can i check? You even did not tell if these values are correct. The strange thing is that you show these values in the buffer before a read. Further: if a fourbytes length is send as start of the message then you did nit shiw the message it self. And if those four bytes are indeed the length then why do you make a string out of them? And then convert that string back to bytes? Please further byte values in hexadecimal notation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in C# DataStream class witch used socket. Try to replace your c# code with following.

```
    SSLStream _clientSocket;
    //DataStream class
    public DataStream(SSLStream clientSocket)
    {
        _clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }
    public void Write(string message)
    {
        int toSendLen = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(message);
        byte[] toSendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
        byte[] toSendLenBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(toSendLen);
        _clientSocket.Write(toSendLenBytes);
        _clientSocket.Write(toSendBytes);
    }
    public String ReadString()
    {
        byte[] rcvLenBytes = new byte[4];
        _clientSocket.Read(rcvLenBytes, 0 , 4);
        int rcvLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(rcvLenBytes, 0);
        byte[] rcvBytes = new byte[rcvLen];
        _clientSocket.Read(rcvBytes, 0, rcvLen);
        var ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rcvBytes);
        return ascii;
    }
```

Comment: This looks like a private conversation. How do you know the server code?

Comment: The c# stream is  correct coz it is working fine with c# TCP server, and you are correct we are sending first 4 bytes as length of data and remaining bytearray as data. When I try to read the SSL stream in android only this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

To read an byte array containing first four bytes filled with length of remaining data use this code

```
        byte[] datalength = new byte[4];
        inputStream.read(datalength, 0, 4);
        //bytebuffer to convert bits of length
        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(datalength);
        //if(use_little_endian)
        byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

        int lengthCount = byteBuffer.getInt();
```